# If $n =\log\left(\frac{\mu}{1-\mu}\right)$, how to show $-\log(1-\mu)=\log(1-e^n)$

Tags: solution-verification

Given $$n =\log\left(\frac{\mu}{1-\mu}\right)$$I need to show that$$
-\log(1-\mu)=\log(1-e^n)
$$

---

From the first equation, $$
-\log(1-\mu)=-\frac{n}{\log(\mu)}
$$
If the question is valid, it means that I can equate:
$$
\log(1-e^n)=-\frac{n}{\log(\mu)}
$$
Which gives$$
\mu=e^{-n/\log(1-e^n)}
$$
However, this won't solve the problem when back substituted on the second equation. This problem arised from showing that the Bernoulli distribution belongs to the exponential family of distributions. Any help will do thank you

Comment: Your first equation $-\log(1-\mu)=-\frac{n}{\log(\mu)}$ is incorrect.

Comment: The correct equation is  $-\log(1-\mu)=n - \log \mu$

Comment: @StefanLafon I see, I treated it as a fraction, let me attempt to solve it thank you.

Comment: The result you want does not follow from the initial equation.  It should be $1+e^n$.

Comment: @David I attempted to try to prove it and it seems that the answer should be $\log(1+e^n)$ not $(1-e^n)$. I am still not sure and reattempts to solve it for the second time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @David, OP's formula is wrong. There is a sign error. Here's the correct one:

Taking the exponential on each side of the original equation  gives
$$e^n = \frac \mu {1-\mu}$$
You can easily solve for $\mu$:
$$(1-\mu)e^n = \mu$$
thus
$$e^n=\mu(1+e^n)$$in other words
$$1-\mu=1-\frac{e^n}{1+e^n}=\frac {1}{1+e^n}$$
which yields $$-\log(1-\mu)=\log(1+e^n)$$

Comment: This does not answer the question as asked.  (Because the question as asked is wrong.)

Comment: Maybe, but it gives the correct answer.

Comment: You are not being very helpful to the OP if you do not point out the error.

Comment: Ha! Just did ! :-P

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I have reversed my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

the conclusion is not true, try $\mu = 1/2$